# Next JS, how to send files uploaded to the front end to the back end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, file-upload, fetch-api

I have a Next application that is a job board. I need to allow the users to upload two files, a resume, and a cover letter. After this, I need to take the files and other information the users provided, then send that information in an email to the employer I have on file for that job posting. The problem I am having is that even though I can get the files and information in a `formData` object when I send it to my API, I am not able to get the files to use.

This is the method I am using to get the information from the front end and put it into a `formData` object.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let form = new FormData(e.target);
    form.append('resume', resume);
    form.append('coverLetter', coverLetter);
    const formData = Object.fromEntries(form.entries());

    console.log(formData);

    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/applyForJob', {
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        method: 'POST',
      });

      const result = await res.json();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error with sending the POST request');
      console.log('Here is the trace');
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Here is the formData object in the console:
[image]

You can clearly see that all the information is there, including the files. Here is the code for the API route:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(typeof req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.candidateEmail);
  console.log(req.resume);
}
```

I should be able to access everything in the request, but here is what the console logs print:

```
string
{"candidateFirstName":"Lawrence","candidateLastName":"Mueller","candidateEmail":"lawrencemueller18@gmail.com","candidatePhone":"16266786830","candidateResume":{},"candidateCoverLetter":{},"resume":{},"coverLetter":{}} 
undefined
[Function (anonymous)]
```

The resume and cover letter fields, show `{}`, so blank. All I need to do is access the files from the front end, just send an email using them. I do not care about storing them at all.

Comment: Try sending the `form` in the body directly `{ body: form, method: 'POST }`, and [disable the built-in body parser](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config) in the API route `export const config = { api: { bodyParser: false } }`.